# Idempotents in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, semigroups, idempotents

Given two idempotents $e,f\in M_2(\mathbb{C})\setminus\{I_2\}$, the sets
$$\{eg^{-1}:g\in GL_2(\mathbb{C}), eg^{-1} \text{ is an idempotent}\}$$
and
$$\{gf:g\in GL_2(\mathbb{C}), gf \text{ is an idempotent}\}$$
are infinite.

Is the following also infinite:
$$\{(eg^{-1},gf):g\in GL_2(\mathbb{C}), gf, eg^{-1} \text{ are idempotents}\}?$$

The motivation behind the question:

It is known that every singular matrix is a product of idempotents. I would like to see if these idempotents can be chosen from some uncountable set.

Comment: So to be clear, you ultimately hope that the third set is uncountable, and you are just presently trying to see if it's infinite? If not, what are you ultimately looking for about that third set?

Comment: @rschwieb If $S$ is an uncountable submonoid of the singular matrices and $x\in S$. I would like to see if $zx\in S$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. We know that $zx$ is a product of idempotents, I would like to know if it is a product of idempotents from $S$. I don't want to get too much into it, but $S$ is of a certain form and has "enough" idempotents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e=0$ or $f=0$, the answer is clearly affirmative. So, it remains to consider the case where both $e,f$ are nonzero but singular idempotent matrices. With a change of basis, we may assume that $f=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}$.

A nonzero but singular $2\times 2$ matrix $X$ is idempotent if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(X)=1$. Therefore, $eg^{-1}$ is idempotent iff
$$
\operatorname{tr}(e\ \operatorname{adj}(g))=\det(g)\ne0.\tag{1}
$$

Let $e=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ and $g=\pmatrix{1&y\\ 0&1}\pmatrix{p&0\\ q&1}$. Then $gf=\pmatrix{0&y\\ 0&1}$ is idempotent for all $y$ and $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
a-bq-cy+dp+dqy=p\ne0.\tag{2}
$$
Now there are two possibilities:

1. $d\ne1$. Then $a$ must be nonzero (otherwise $a+d\ne1$ and $e$ is not idempotent). So, $(2)$ is satisfied by putting $q=0$ and $p=(a-cy)/(1-d)$ with $a-cy\ne0$.
2. $d=1$. Then $a=0$ and $(2)$ is equivalent to the two conditions $(y-b)q=cy,\ p\ne0$, which are satisfied by putting $q=cy/(y-b)$ with $y\ne b$ and any $p\ne0$.

In each of the above two cases, there are uncountably infinitely many choices of feasible $y$. As $gf=\pmatrix{0&y\\ 0&1}$ varies with $y$, the last set mentioned in the question is uncountably infinite.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't state it in the question but I meant non unit idempotents.

Comment: It probably doesn't change it a lot, but naturally b and c can be both zero. Just take b=c=0 and then either a=0 and d=1 or a=1 and d=0...

Comment: @Yatir You are right. See the new edit.

Comment: I think there is something more that needs to be said. There might be infinitely many $g$ that give the same pair $(eg^{-1},gf)$. How do you know that there aren't only finitely many pairs but countable many $g$s?

Comment: @Yatir $g$ is specified by four parameters $x,y,z,w$, in which $w$ and $y$ are (mostly) free, $z$ depends on $w,y$ and $x=yz/(w-1)$. Now, as long as $w\ne1,\ y\ne0,\ y\ne b(w-1)/a\ $ (if $a\ne0$) and $y\ne(1-dw)/c\ $ (if $c\ne0$), every pair of choices of $(w,y)$ will give rise to a feasible solution $g$. In particular, if you fix $w\ne1$, all but at most three values of $y$ will give you feasible solutions. The real line has uncountably infinitely many values. Take away three of them, you still have uncountably infinitely many values.

Comment: That I understand. But there might (and there are) infinitely many $(x,y,z,w)$ that give the same pair $(eg^{-1},gf)$.

Comment: @Yatir I have rewritten the answer. Hope it's clearer now.